Equally scaling and offsetting a 3D triangular mesh
I would like to do equally scaling and offsetting along the facets normals a 3D triangular mesh such as the on in the image below.

I would like to move each triangle along their own inward normal and scale them by a factor.
I tried different things such as scaling, but this works fine for the x and y coordinates but not for the z one. I have not been able to apply the offset function for a 3D shape.
I would like to obtain a new 3D shape which is smaller along the x and y axis and smaller along the z axis but not at the basis of the femur.
By doing so, I would be able to substract the new 3D shape from the original one and obtain the new one as shown here

The code below equally scale the original shape with respect to its centroid, but it's not what I would like to get...
Do you have any idea or suggestion?
The original shape can be downloaded here
https://filesender.renater.fr/?s=download&token=f6593eb0-3231-4536-943d-f8276ee07706
    (* Import the stl file 'femur', compute the centroid of the 3D shape, scaling by a factor 0.8 with respect to the centroid *)
femur = Import["proximal.stl", 
   "MeshRegion"];
    centroid = Mean /@ RegionBounds[femur];
    scaling = ScalingTransform[{0.8, 0.8, 0.8}, centroid];
    Graphics3D[{{Opacity[.35], Blue, femur}, 
      GeometricTransformation[{Opacity[.85], Red, femur}, scaling]}, 
     Boxed -> False]


I don't know how to upload the original .stl file here?

Google drive and share?

the link to download the .stl is in the text

Or Clear[reg]; reg = ShellRegion[Import["proximal.stl", "BoundaryMeshRegion"], .01]; Graphics3D[{Opacity[.2], reg}]

Edit

ShellRegion

Clear[reg];
reg = ShellRegion[Import["proximal.stl", "BoundaryMeshRegion"], .01]; 
Graphics3D[{Opacity[.2], reg}]


The hollow mesh.

Clear["Global`*"];
femur = Import["proximal.stl", "BoundaryMeshRegion"];
dist = SignedRegionDistance[femur];
bd = RegionBounds[femur];
bd2 = CoordinateBoundingBox[Transpose@bd, .09];
plot = ContourPlot3D[
   dist@{x, y, z}, {x, y, z} ∈ Cuboid @@ bd2, 
   RegionBoundaryStyle -> None, BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
   Contours -> {-.005}, Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
   PlotPoints -> 80, MaxRecursion -> 0];
reg = DiscretizeGraphics[plot];
bm = BoundaryMeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[reg], MeshCells[reg, 2]];
diff = RegionDifference[femur, bm];
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], FaceForm[Opacity[.2]], diff}, Boxed -> False]



For the old Mathematica version,maybe use (only test in 11.3 version)

Clear["Global`*"];
femur = Import["proximal.stl", "BoundaryMeshRegion"];
dist = SignedRegionDistance[femur];
bd = RegionBounds[femur];
bd2 = CoordinateBoundingBox[Transpose@bd, .09];
{{xmin, ymin, zmin}, {xmax, ymax, zmax}} = bd2;
plot = ContourPlot3D[
   dist@{x, y, z}, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}, {z, zmin, zmax}, 
   BoxRatios -> Automatic, Contours -> {-.01}, Mesh -> None, 
   Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 0];
reg = DiscretizeGraphics[plot];
bm = BoundaryMeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[reg], MeshCells[reg, 2]];
diff = BoundaryMeshRegion[
  Join[MeshCoordinates[femur], 
   MeshCoordinates[bm]], {MeshCells[femur, 2, "Multicells" -> True], 
   Polygon[Length[MeshCoordinates[femur]] + 
     MeshCells[bm, 2, "Multicells" -> True][[1, -1]]]}];
RegionPlot3D[diff, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.2], Boxed -> False]
Volume[femur] == Volume[diff] + Volume[bm]



True

Original
Maybe SignedRegionDistance+ ContourPlot3D.
femur = Import["proximal.stl", "BoundaryMeshRegion"];
dist = SignedRegionDistance[femur];
bd = RegionBounds[femur];
bd2 = CoordinateBoundingBox[Transpose@bd, .09];
plot = ContourPlot3D[
   dist@{x, y, z}, {x, y, z} ∈ Cuboid @@ bd2, 
   RegionBoundaryStyle -> None, BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
   Contours -> {-.005}];
Graphics3D[{plot[[1]], Opacity[.2], femur}, Boxed -> False]



not bad at all! would it be possible to do the same but keeping fixed the bottom boundary ? meaning scaling only along the x and y directions and not the vertical one?

Actually I would like to obtain a new mesh of the orange plot to be substracted from the original one and obtain a hollow mesh...

thanks, however the discretization of plot does not work on my side...I got this error when executing BoundaryMeshRegion: 'The boundary surface is not closed because the edges Line[...] only come from a single face.'

@moimoi I am using version14.1 in Windows.

ouch, I have version 12...

do you think there is a way to bypass this issue?

It works in Mathematica 12 now, but why you join coordinates instead of compute the difference between the 2 shapes to obtain a hollow one?

@moimoi This is the functon of BoundaryMeshRegion, see the low dimension examples. {BoundaryMeshRegion[{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}}, {Point[{1, 4}],     Point[{2, 3}]}],   BoundaryMeshRegion[{{0, 0}, {3, 0}, {3, 3}, {0, 3}, {1, 1}, {2,      1}, {2, 2}, {1, 2}}, Line[{1, 2, 3, 4, 1}],    Line[{5, 6, 7, 8, 5}]]}
